# Нужна функция для получение частотно-амплитудного спектра звука.

Tags: аудио, delphi, визуализация

вот пример
[image]

или так (тут как раз видно то что мне нужно)
[image]

(нужно для попытки разобрать речь. точнее отдельные буквы)

Comment: а что вы пробовали сами ? я в этом плохо разбираюсь, знаю только слово Фурье

Comment: по картинках не нашол, а так даже не знаю что искать(

Answer (score 1):

И как вы представляете себе функцию? на входе звук на выходе картинка?

Вопрос вполне решаемый но на платной основе.
да и для распознавания речи мало пригодно, есть более практичные алгоритмы.

Ну а если просто есть желание построить спектроанализатор, то посмотриите в сторону bass.dll

Comment: ну можно и картинку, а вообще я матрицу ожидал.

>>Вопрос вполне решаемый но на платной основе.
Если хотите, могу скинуть ссилку на проект на фрилансе. Может Вам удастся?

За Bass.dll спасибо)

Comment: А вас что поставили исполнителем? или вы думаете я на фрилансе этого проекта не увижу?

Comment: Да. Я предлагал использовать гугл, а он не понимает отдельных букв.

Зачем иронизируете? Нет так нет.

Comment: Что-то RAD Studio XE4 не хочет создавать модуль с заголовками к dll... жаль.

Comment: понимает гугль отдельные буквы, перечитайте доки и требования к файлам , вполне сносное решение получается , на Хабре есть статья по этому поводу.

Comment: по статье-же делал...

Comment: Ну наверное что то не доделал или не дочитал, или не совсем понял.
Если вы заказчик на фрилансе это одно, если исполнитель то другое, а если просто для развития то это третье.

Если есть реальное предложение по сотрудничеству пишите на почту есть в профиле.